# How many stereogenic centres are there in discodermolide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image: Structure of discodermolide]
It is generally said that carbon-carbon double bonds cannot behave as stereogenic centres but the above molecule contains three such centres. Can somebody please point out all the stereogenic centres (including the double bonded carbons) and explain how and why this is so?

Comment: I'm confused.  Who is saying the C=C double bounds are stereogenic?  Various materials I find, including (this one)[http://www.scs.illinois.edu/denmark/presentations/2004/gm-2004-07_06.pdf], say it has 13 stereocenters.  That is the same as the number of carbons connected to "stereo" bold or hashed bonds.  None of those carbons have double bonds.  Why do you think it contains C=C stereocenters?  Please consider editing your question to explain in more detail.

Comment: @CurtF. I am confused, too. Who is saying, that carbon-carbon double bonds are not stereogenic? Interchanging the substitutes at these centres would lead to a different stereoisomer (as long as the substituents are different of course). Unfortunately the definition is not given in the goldbook and hence not straight forward.

Comment: Can you give your definition of stereogenic centre. Are you referring to chiral centres?

Comment: Strange it seems there's cis/trans and R/S confusion, but they're totally different isomerisms.

Comment: OK, I just looked up "stereocenter" and "stereogenic" and to my surprise these terms supposedly include the cis-trans isomerism of C=C bonds as well as chiral isomerism.  In that case, however, many of the popular descriptions of the discodermolide are wrong, because in many places the molecule is referred to as having 13 stereocenters.  But if you include the C=C bond "stereocenters", the total would go up to three more.

Comment: The IUPAC Gold Book does include E/Z double bond isomers in its definition of 'stereogenic', which makes sense. I'm surprised that there's no definition of 'stereocenter'. I would NOT include double bonds in counting stereocenters because the E/Z designation is defined by the substitution at two atoms (all carbon in this case). In my mind, a stereocenter is limited to the classic 'four different things attached to one atom (carbon)'. I would say that discodermolide has 13 stereocenters and 16 stereogenic units. http://goldbook.iupac.org/S05980.html

Comment: There are 3 E/Z olefins and 16 asymmetric carbons total. The answer is 16. The entire olefin (both carbons) are a stereogenic center. It is the involvement of both carbons of the double bond (their juxtaposition) that makes the molecule otherwise than it would be. These designations are binary...R/S, E/Z, there is no other way to have the generation of stereoisomers (configurational isomers) arise. Consider how many maximum possible stereoisomers you can have. Now do you really think it matters if semantics calls it a 'unit' or a 'center'?

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

The confusion probably arises because of incompletely standardized definitions of at least some subset of the words "stereocenter", "stereogenic", "stereogenic center", "stereogenic unit".

## IUPAC definitions

The place to turn for authoritative definitions of these terms is IUPAC's Gold Book, as noted by @jerepierre in the comments.  Here is what it has to say:

> #### [stereogenic unit](http://goldbook.iupac.org/D01679.html) (stereogen/stereoelement)
>
> *A grouping within a molecular entity that may be considered a focus of stereoisomerism.*
>
> At least one of these must be present in every enantiomer (though the
>   presence of stereogenic units does not conversely require the
>   corresponding chemical species to be chiral). Three basic types are
>   recognized for molecular entities involving atoms having not more than
>   four substituents:
>
> 1. A grouping of atoms consisting of a central atom and distinguishable
>      ligands, such that the interchange of any two of the substituents
>      leads to a stereoisomer. An asymmetric atom (chirality centre) is
>      the traditional example of this stereogenic unit.
> 2. A chain of four non-coplanar atoms (or rigid groups) in a stable conformation, such that an imaginary or real (restricted) rotation
>      (with a change of sign of the torsion angle) about the central bond
>      leads to a stereoisomer.
> 3. A grouping of atoms consisting of a double bond with substituents which give rise to cis-trans isomerism.

Thus, the unequally substituted C=C moieties in discodermolide are "stereogenic units" according to IUPAC.

#### Stereocenter

Unfortunately, this term is not defined in IUPAC's Gold Book.

#### Stereogenic center

Unfortunately, this term is not defined in IUPAC's Gold Book.

## Wikipedia

Wikipedia is not as authoritative as IUPAC but it is likely that chem.se readers will encounter wikipedia entries for these terms far more often than IUPAC's in the course of regular web searching.

#### Stereogenic unit

No Wikipedia entry

#### Stereogenic center

Redirects to "stereocenter", see below.

#### [Stereocenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereocenter)

> *A stereocenter or stereogenic center is an *atom* bearing groups such that an interchanging of any two groups leads to a stereoisomer.*

This definition does not apply to C=C double bonds, because only an *atom* can be a stereocenter, not a group of atoms.  Supporting this interpretation is a complete lack of reference to cis-trans isomerism on the rest of the page.

## Usage by chemists

Discodermolide is referred to in many sources as having 13 "stereocenters" or "stereogenic" centers.  This conforms with the Wikipedia, atom-centric definition of stereocenter.  Here are some example sources:

- [Wikipedia's discodermolide article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discodermolide): *(+)-discodermolide has
  ...13 stereogenic centers...*
- [A presentation from 2004](http://www.scs.illinois.edu/denmark/presentations/2004/gm-2004-07_06.pdf):
  *molecule possesses: 13 stereocenters*
- [A paper from 2003](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo034901c): Paper title: *Regulated-Stereoselective Construction of Thirteen
  Stereogenic Centers...*

All these uses comport with both Wikipedia definitions of "stereocenter"/"stereogenic center".  Chemists do not seem to use the IUPAC term "stereogenic unit" very much in actual practice.   I could not find any relevant pages using both the term "discodermolide" and the phrase "stereogenic unit", for example.

## Bottom line

It is just possible to pass a thread of consistency through the eye of this needle of confusing terminology.

1. Discodermolide has thirteen (13) stereogenic *centers*.
2. Each of those stereogenic centers is by definition also a stereocenter, and is also a "stereogenic unit".
3. In addition to those 13 stereocenters, there are three additional "stereogenic units" in discodermolide corresponding to the unequally substituted C=C bonds.

Comment: I've probably heard 'stereogenic element' or 'stereoelement' more often than 'stereogenic unit' in practice. Now that I've seen 'stereogenic unit' in the Gold Book, I'll probably go with that to stay away from 'element' which obviously has a unique meaning to chemistry.