# Are alkenes with bulky groups attached (like the one shown in the picture) chiral or achiral?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

> Is the compound in the picture chiral or achiral?
>
> [image: (2E)-3-(3-bromo-2,4,6-trimethylphenyl)-3-chloro-2-methylprop-2-enoic acid]

I think it should be achiral for the following reasons:

- There is free rotation. I know, but for every configuration produced by free rotation there is an exactly opposite configuration.
- Also at certain point of time all the groups can come to the same plane.

This question is from my textbook exercise. And the answer says it is chiral. But I've no idea why. Also is it optically active or inactive?

EDIT:
@K_P gave a very useful [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403901873433/part/first-page-pdf) related to these type of compounds:

Comment: Is there free rotation around the bond between the phenyl ring and the double bond?

Comment: I think so @K_P tell me if I am wrong

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37794/when-can-a-molecule-be-considered-freely-rotating-at-room-temperature

Comment: Have you sudied [atropisomerism](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Atropisomer)? It is a very important topic and your exercise is an example of this

Comment: also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24901/do-molecules-with-axial-chirality-have-stereogenic-units

Comment: @K_P  I read it now. But how to understand whether the group is bulky enough for atropisomerism ?

Comment: Your picture is not right, you need to draw the methyl groups (and the bromine atom) on the benzene ring so it will be more clear why there is hindered rotation. If this is useful at all, I was not sure if there is atropisomerism, I assumed there was, because of the answer in your textbook and then did some googling that confirms it: [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403901873433/part/first-page-pdf)

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/35515/14857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the compound in the picture chiral or achiral?

The answer in practice is: **it depends.** You say that there would be free rotation along the phenyl–vinyl bond. However, *every* adjacent carbon atom — the 2- and 6-positions of the phenyl ring and the 1-position of the double bond — are substituted. For free rotation to occur, these substituents must pass each other. Since they are all bulky, though, free rotation is very effectively hindered. A planar rotamer with full π conjugation between the phenyl ring and the double bond is not populated at any extend which can be shown by the NMR shifts of the corresponding carbon atoms (and could also be shown if the methyl group on the double bond were a proton, because it’s shift would be vastly different from one in styryl conjugation).

Under low enough temperatures, the compound you have been given will indeed form to *separable* enantiomers due to the bromine atom which destroys the molecule’s symmetry. These are examples of axial chirality; if the chlorine atom is above the phenyl ring’s plane, it is (a*R*), if it is below, the compound is (a*S*). The two enantiomers can be separated, e.g. by chiral HPLC, and they will show optical activity.

At higher temperatures, thermal energy will be enough to overcome the rotation barrier and an optically active single enantiomer will racemise. This temperature is typically above room temperature for a system such as your’s but well below the temperature required for alkene (*E*/*Z*) isomerisation.

This concept is called [atropisomerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atropisomer) and is also the reason why BINOL and BINAP are chiral.

Comment: Do you know of any web resource which has listed down all known atropisomers ?

Comment: @S007 *All known* is wa~y too broad; I don’t think that even all bisphenyl-based atropisomers are listed anywhere.  Unless of course you’re talking about different *conceptual building blocks* but then again I still don’t know. (But at least the list would be manageable.)