# Why does cyclooctene have three stereoisomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

How does cyclooctene have three stereoisomers?

I thought that there are only two stereoisomers, cis- and trans-, but according to my textbook there are *three* stereoisomers. I want to know how?

Comment: Could be helpful https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35470/why-is-trans-cyclooctene-chiral